# I'm unsure about permissions on C:\Users\Public and \Default

Tags: windows, security

What folder permissions are acceptable for the windows folders:
c:\Users\Public
c:\Users\Default (Hidden folder)

Comment: What’s wrong with the default permissions?

Comment: I am uncomfortable with the Everyone, Interactive and Account Unknown permissions

Comment: Account Unknown likely comes from an account that no longer exists. Most folders outside of a user profile and a protected folder are already accessible to everyone on the machine.

Comment: Default and Public folders generally work as designed. Do not keep data in these folders, but rather in your own User folder.

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: Acceptable by who?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Windows 10 computer, from your list `C:\Users\Public` has only
INTERACTIVE while `C:\Users\Default` has only `Everyone`.

None of the two folders should have permissions for individual users,
so whatever was previously the defunct account "Unknown",
the permission shouldn't have existed then, and you can delete it now.

INTERACTIVE is not worrisome, since this identity isn't a group that
you can manually place members into, but is rather added by the
operating system automatically when a security token is constructed
for a user who has logged-on via the Windows Graphical User Interface.
This is not a real user permission and cannot be used to access
this folder.

The folder `C:\Users\Default` must have the `Everyone` permission.
The contents of this folder are copied to every new user account
on the system. When a new user profile is created, it copies its
default settings and files to its profile directory.
Removing the `Everyone` permission would cause every addition of
new users to fail, resulting in a badly-formatted user profile.

In conclusion, the permissions are correct, except for this weird
account named "Unknown" which is the result of some past user action
or a weird product installation.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information -you have been extremely helpful